# make a blob file trigger a BlobTrigger Azure Function at specific time

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have found that there is BlobTrigger Azure Fucntion, but I don't want a blob file trigger a BlobTrigger Azure Function immediately after blob updated, I hope a blob file can trigger a BlobTrigger Azure Function at specific time. Does BlobTrigger Azure Function support this kindof operation?

make a blob file trigger a BlobTrigger Azure Function at specific time

Answer (score 1):

The Azure Blob Trigger by essence is polling the container/blob storage it is listening to. So when it detects it, it will try to process that blob. You need to override the basic functionality of the Blob Storage trigger in order to achieve what you want.

One solution I am thinking of now is to use a time-based trigger; for that you need to update your `function.json` (this example triggers the function every `3` hours):

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */3 * * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can check more information here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=python-v1%2Cin-process&pivots=programming-language-python

Additional examples taken from the docs:

NCRONTAB examples
Here are some examples of NCRONTAB expressions you can use for the timer trigger in Azure Functions.

```
Example                 When triggered

0 */5 * * * *           once every five minutes
0 0 * * * *             once at the top of every hour
0 0 */2 * * *           once every two hours
0 0 9-17 * * *          once every hour from 9 AM to 5 PM
0 30 9 * * *            at 9:30 AM every day
0 30 9 * * 1-5          at 9:30 AM every weekday
0 30 9 * Jan Mon        at 9:30 AM every Monday in January
```